# SQL Server stored procedure error on INSERT

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure for `INSERT`, lately I noticed I am getting unusual errors one doesn't seems to be like one

I get following error when I try to compile the following stored procedure:

> *Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure usp_AddArticleCategory, Line 15
>
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ArtcileCategoryActive".*

This is my code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AddArticleCategory]
    @ArticleCategoryName nvarchar(200),
    @LangID int,
    @ArticleCategoryActive bit,
    @Type nvarchar(100)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO art_Category (ArticleCategoryName,[LangID],ArtcileCategoryActive,[Type])
         VALUES (@ArticleCategoryName, @LangID, @ArtcileCategoryActive, @Type)
END
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[art_Category](
    [ArticleCategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ArticleCategoryName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [LangID] [int] NULL,
    [ArtcileCategoryActive] [bit] NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_art_Category] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ArticleCategoryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I compared table columns, datatypes but I am not sure why this error keeps coming.

Appreciate help with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring;

```
ArticleCategoryActive
```

and using;

```
ArtcileCategoryActive
```

Spot the difference? :)

Comment: One needs hawk eye for this, Thanks it is working... This mistake get me often